# make elements above other in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am using one custom control (jQuery cycle plugin, to be specific), and I also have a drop-down menu on my web page. The custom control appears to be above the drop-down menu, which doesn't suit me at all. How can I make my drop-down menu be above everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `z-index` property. More information at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Keep in mind that `z-index` works only with positioned elements.

A good "how to use" article about `z-index` you can find [here](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/css-how-to-use-the-z-index-property/).